# Javascript decodeURIComponent not working with MySQL Date

Tags: javascript, mysql

Type this into Firebug's javascript console:

`decodeURIComponent('2011-03-13+00:00:00')`

I get `'2011-03-13+00:00:00'`. Same with unescape().

Is this intended behavior?? I really need to decode all my URI components...

Comment: @Luke the "+" was a " " before i submitted it through a form using get.

Comment: hm, im asking because encoded your string would look like this "2011-03-13%2000%3A00%3A00"

Comment: @Luke that is strange, I hadn't realized that the colons aren't encoded. The space between 13 and 00 did get converted to a plus, but that's it. I'll need to inspect the situation further. :)